# Giving up the time slice for current thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Are the following statements equivalent ways for giving up the time slice for the current thread?

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
std::this_thread::yield;
Sleep(0);  // On windows
```

Comment: `std::this_thread::yield()` might be, but the bare function reference probably isn't ;-)

Comment: When do you need to "give up the time slice" ? this blog made me rethink the need for those: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/06/05/in-praise-of-idleness/

Comment: @Bahbar I'm still really confused about this `yield` and "give up the time slice" but the blog/website you shared seems dead. By any chance, do you have a link for any other useful resources, articles, videos, or something? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Milan: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/in-praise-of-idleness/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not equivalent. `std::this_thread::yield` should map to `sched_yield` and `SwitchToThread`, respectively. I'm saying "should" because if depend on the implementation, of course.

These give up the current timeslice and reschedule. `SwitchToThread` only respects threads on the current CPU but makes no statment about the calling thread's position in the ready queue other than *if there is another thread ready on the same CPU, that one runs first*.
`sched_yield` *moves the thread to the end* of the ready queue and reschedules.

`Sleep(0)` does more or less the same under Windows, except it is more unreliable (it's not at all impossible to have `Sleep(0)` return after 50-100ms!) and it does not respect CPU boundaries, i.e. a thread that would run on another CPU might get moved. No issue on a "normal household" dualcore, big issue on a NUMA server.

`nanosleep(timespec_with_zero_ns)` (i.e. under Linux/BSD/POSIX/whatever) really does what you ask for, it sleeps for zero time, i.e. not at all. It's just a useless context switch that returns immediately (we've actually had this happen once, it's surprising when you *assume* it just works like under Windows).

Comment: I don't believe your comment about `Sleep` always waiting for 50-100ms is correct. According to MSDN - `A value of zero causes the thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run. If there are no other threads ready to run, the function returns immediately, and the thread continues execution.`

Comment: @MarkIngram: I did not say that it **always** waits for 50-100ms. I said it **can** easily wait for that time. The way sleep (on any platform) works is it makes the current thread _not-ready_, meaning it will not be scheduled. It then, at a later time, makes the thread _ready_ (the conditions depend heavily on the OS, even different Windows versions differ!). Which means it will from now on be scheduled again. However, "will be scheduled" is _not the same_ as "will run". It only means as much as "is a candidate for running". A long time may pass before the thread actually runs again.

Comment: Yes, but it only does this if you use a value greater than zero, or you use zero and there is another thread waiting to do the work, else it returns immediately and continues execution with no context switch.

Answer (score 6):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Sleep for:
'Blocks the execution of the current thread for specified sleep_duration. **May block for longer than sleep_duration.**'

It really depend of the implementation, and the operating system.

std::this_thread::yield() is the standard way (the non-specific-implementation dependent) to give up the time slice.