# std::this_thread::yield() vs std::this_thread::sleep_for()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

What is the difference between C++11 `std::this_thread::yield()` and `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`? How to decide when to use which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving up the time slice for current thread in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048657/giving-up-the-time-slice-for-current-thread-in-c)

Comment: It does not seem to be answered there.

Comment: `yield` does not throw. `sleep_for` may throw.

Comment: @dirkgently `sleep_for` also doesn't throw if the chrono::duration types do not throw, which is true for the standard ones, see 30.3.2.9

Comment: NOTE: Use of Yields is a bad sign in programs.  Basically it means that you don't have enough synchronization (i.e. you're not really tracking who's waiting on a resource and who is responsible for waking up the waiters).

Comment: @NeerajSingh, even if we are aware of wait dependency among the threads, sometimes OS schedules threads in such a way that it becomes a necessity to intervene on time-slice management and use option like `yield()`. However I have noticed that even `yield()` is also not enough.

Comment: yield will incur thread context switch while sleep_for will not. So yield will probably save some cpu time but thread switch also has overhead. Use yield when the potential waiting time is long, otherwise sleep_for should be used.

Comment: @NeerajSingh I have used yield in loop when receiving data inside a thread via DBUS, I have no idea when DBUS from other programs will produce data. Ideally I would like to use something like epoll that monitors fd for received data so guess work is eliminated. However, I don't have that luxury with current implementation of receiving data on lock free queue.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`std::this_thread::yield` tells the implementation to reschedule the execution of threads, that should be used in a case where you are in a busy waiting state, like in a thread pool:

```
...
while(true) {
  if(pool.try_get_work()) {
    // do work
  }
  else {
    std::this_thread::yield(); // other threads can push work to the queue now
  }
}
```

`std::this_thread::sleep_for` can be used if you really want to  wait for a specific amount of time. This can be used for task, where timing really matters, e.g.: if you really only want to wait for 2 seconds. (Note that the implementation might wait longer than the given time duration)

Comment: So, does it mean that std::this_thread::yield will give up execution for 'some time' and the try again? How does the thread work out when o try next time?

Comment: @polapts Yes, `std::this_thread::yield` just allows the scheduler to execute an other thread. When the scheduler comes back to this thread, it will just work on after the call to `std::this_thread::yield`

Answer (score 26):

> std::this_thread::sleep_for()

will make your thread sleep for a given time (the thread is stopped for a given time).
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

> std::this_thread::yield()

will stop the execution of the current thread and give priority to other process/threads (if there are other process/threads waiting in the queue).
The execution of the thread is not stopped. (it just release the CPU).
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield)